# Use a URL Pattern for <%@include file=" ..."%>

Tags: jsp, servlets

I want to add another JSP Page(Example: a header page) to a main JSP page. I want to avoid writing the real jsp page name. Therefore I write some another name,let's say "topbanner". 
Here is it in code

```
<%@include file="topbanner"%>
```

The real page is topheader.jsp and it is located in project
->web->header->topheader.jsp

In my deployment descriptor (web.xml), I have mapped the topheader.jsp in web.xml

```
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>pagetop</servlet-name>
        <jsp-file>/header/topheader.jsp</jsp-file>
    </servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>pagetop</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/topbanner</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

But this doesn't work. it throws exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /index.jsp (line: 11, column: 1) File "/topbanner" not found
```

Any one let me know where the problem is and how can I fix it with a sample code.

**EDIT**
Can't I use `<%@include file=" ..."%>` for mapped jsp s ?

Answer (score 1):

Static **<%@ ... >** JSP includes the text inside the path given. If you are looking to include another JSP on top or bottom , you should use `prelude and code`.

**Here is the sample:**

```
<jsp-config>
  <jsp-property-group>
     <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
     <include-prelude>/header.jsp</include-prelude>
     <include-coda>/footer.jsp</include-coda>
  </jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

- `Prelude` is added in the beginning.
- `Coda` is added at the end.

**Here are some tutorials:**

- [Automatically including preludes and coda](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=602)
- [Defining Implicit Includes](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19575-01/819-3669/bnajl/index.html)

Comment: Thank you very much.I got a new point for using headers and bottom banners.

Comment: I tried your code.But id didn't work.I created a sample project which has index.jsp,footer.jsp,header.jsp and above code in web.xml. in jsp page also I used the `include file`. will u explain more please?(how to use `include file` in jsp page) . Also lets say, I need to include a jsp page into only one particular jsp page. Then how can I use prelude and coda ?

Comment: It should work, not sure why it did not work. For including in one particular page, you can give absolute path in the <url-pattern>. like, <url-pattern>index.jsp</url-pattern>

Comment: It worked well. I have made a mistake in web.xml before... Thank you very much Mr. Ramesh PVK

Comment: One more thing. `Static <%@ ... > JSP includes the text inside the path given.` then `<%@include file..` can ONLY be used only to get text(html elements) printed? can't we use including file for some functions(example: the header.jsp checks whether a user is loged or not,if not, redirect to another page using scriplets)? Also, can't we use a url mapped name for `include file` as I mentioned in my question ?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

1. Create a servlet with mapping of "tapbanner" in web.xml
2. Override the `doGet()` method in `Topbanner` servlet
3. `Forward` or `Include` the `topbanner.jsp` in the `doGet()` using `RequestDispatcher`

Comment: hm.. `The mapping in web.xml is for servlets only` .As far as I know, it can be done for JSP as well. Normal html elements (example: <a href="..") calls such jsp mapped jsp files. [Here](http://www.xyzws.com/JSPfaq/how-to-config-a-jsp-file-in-webxml/2) a sample article too. My problem doesn't work in `include file` and I want to solve how to do with `include file`

Comment: Oops sorry for that..got a new pinch.. :), well did you try `include` tag? `<jsp:include page="relativeURL" />  or <jsp:include page="relativeURL"></jsp:include>`